# unselecting first folder causes all placemarks to disappear

Tags: xml, google-maps, kml

I am bewildered at the following behavior.

When I deselect the first folder here, all the placemarks disappear:

http://goo.gl/maps/htwQA

The full KML file is here:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/cfe28a5dd35d9c7ff2f55de152917c6fc868688f1ef39e2ea71b3043.kml

Has anyone had a similar experience? I am specifically segmenting the placemarks inside a KML file. I would like the user to be able to choose which folder of placemarks is visible.

For some reason, when the user checks/unchecks the first folder all the placemarks disappear.

I've tried this on other similar KML files that I have created and the behavior is consistent with this.

**Why are all the placemarks disappearing?**

Comment: I see the problem on Google Maps, but can't access the KML directly. Might be something in your KML file, but hard to tell.

Comment: @geocodezip thank you so much again for looking. the KML file shoudl work now can you please check it once more

Comment: @geocodezip just wondering if you might have seen anything in the KML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your KML file has a ' in it before the first folder, I thought that might be confusing the parser.

```
    </Style>'<Folder><name>SuboxonePrescribers</name>
```

But removing it still has the problem:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fdisappearing_placemark_test_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=44.460291,-89.724498&sspn=12.526662,19.533691&t=h&z=6

My current theory is this is a bug in the KML parser.  The KML is [valid](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fdisappearing_placemark_test_kml.xml)

Comment: here is how i fixed the issue. i created an empty folder: http://goo.gl/maps/37BdQ  please let me know what you think

Comment: did you get a chance to look at that link above>? what are your thoughts?